# How to tile a texture over a cube in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

My issue looks like this:

[image]

The wood simply tiles improperly. I have given it a smart UV unwrap and basic texture coordinates and it is looking pretty bad. I want it to tile properly, as the texture should, and not in a random way as you can tell from the picture.

This is my node graph:

[image]

How do I get the wood to tile seamlessly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically it's a UV problem:

[image]

If faces A and B can be contiguous, at least one between B and E or A and E (my case) will not be seamless, unless you want this effect which is really fake:

[image]

Anyway, for the first option, in edit mode select those edges: AE, ED, EC, DC, AF, FD, FC; Mark as seams, U to Unwrap.

For the second option place your viewport as you want to see the cube, select all vertices and press U "project from view".

I noticed also that in your node system the coordinates mapping affects only one of the 3 textures, which generally is an error.